# $domxpath->query - In order: <h2> -> <div> -> <p>

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domparser

How do I access the contents of the paragraph that is inside the `div` that is after the tag `</h2>`?

```
$domxpath->query('//h2[*[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]]/parent::div[@class="cabecalho"]/following-sibling::p[position() = 1]');
```

html excerpt:

```
    <div _ngcontent-3a8d-21="" class="cabecalho" id="cont">
                <div _ngcontent-3a8d-21="" class="cabecalho__celula-esquerda">
                    <h2 _ngcontent-3a8d-21="" class="cabecalho__titulo">Território e Ambiente</h2>
                </div>

                <!--template bindings={}-->
                <div _ngcontent-3a8d-21="" class="cabecalho__celula-direita cabecalho__celula-direita--fader">

                    <p _ngcontent-3a8d-21="" class="cabecalho__descricao">

                        content paragraph

                    </p>

                    <div _ngcontent-3a8d-21="" class="mobile-exclusive cabecalho__descricao__showhide">
                        <i _ngcontent-3a8d-21="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-down cabecalho__descricao__bt--show"></i>
                        <i _ngcontent-3a8d-21="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-up cabecalho__descricao__bt--hide"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I tried with the above query and similar attempts but it is not returning the paragraph

Comment: `p` tag is a child of `div` not a sibling.

Comment: @revo How do I add child? I tried that and it did not work `//h2[*[contains(text(), "Território e Ambiente")]]/div[@class="cabecalho__celula-direita"]/p[position() = 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not traversing right paths. `parent::div` asserts but not traverses. `p` is a descendant of `div` element not a sibling. `div` is not an element after `h2`, it's in another path so it's after another `div`.

You are basically doing this:

```
$domxpath->query('
    //h2[contains(., "Território e Ambiente")]/../following-sibling::div/p
');
```

Comment: thank you revo, this works, on the `.` before the comma what does he do?`(., "Território e Ambiente")]/../` are the two points followed a separator to indicate that it is in different divs?

Comment: Single dot  denotes current node. `../` denotes parent node.